# (UK rail travel) Where can you exchange a Permit to Travel for a ticket?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets

If taking a suburban train in London and buying a Permit to Travel, bought at dedicated vending machines for any amount less than the full fare, to be exchanged for an actual ticket later by paying the difference, where does one exchange the permit for an actual ticket?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You exchange the permit for a ticket if you are asked to present your ticket onboard the train by a guard, ticket inspector or revenue protection officer - they will charge you the difference between the permit value and the ticket you require to conduct your journey, or refund the difference if the permit is worth more than the ticket for your journey (unlikely).

You may also be asked to purchase the full ticket from a ticket office if you present the permit at an exit barrier inspector, if that ticket office is open.

From the National Rail penalty fares FAQ:

> If you are unable to do so, you must buy a Permit to Travel from the machines that are provided at most stations. ***This permit must be upgraded to a valid ticket at the first opportunity***.

http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/46592.aspx

If you are not challenged onboard or at your destination station, the proper approach is to voluntarily go to the nearest open ticket office and exchange the permit.

In practice, if you remain unchallenged, you just got yourself some cheap train travel.

Comment: "You may also be asked to purchase the full ticket from a ticket office if you present the permit at an exit barrier inspector," How do you even get out through the barrier with just a permit if it's not manned? Literally, how do you not get stuck inside the station (and no, jumping over it doesn't count)

Comment: @Crazydre if a station is unmanned, the ticket barriers will not be closed.  If the ticket barriers are closed, there is someone trackside at the station - guaranteed.

Comment: I see, do you happen to know whether the barriers are usually open or closed at Luton Airport Parkway on Saturdays around 17:00?

Comment: @Crazydre no idea, never been there.  But as its an airport station, I would pretty much guarantee its always manned and thus always has active barriers.

Comment: Some stations have enough unpaid tickets/permits to travel that the ticket office has a window trackside (or there's a special ticket desk in rush hour).  I doubt that's the case at an airport station.  If you know the fare, going a touch over with your permit to travel *should* save you time -- you could ignore "go to the ticket office to reclaim your 20p" if you're checked at the gateline.

Comment: @ChrisH the moral of the story is, with regard to Permits to Travel, that you always under pay when you buy the Permit to Travel, but don't shy away when someone asks you to upgrade it.  That way you can never be prosecuted, and you also never lose money.

Comment: @Moo as a general rule I completely agree (though I believe there are rules to stop you taking advantage). As the OP was going to an airport I suggested a minimal overpayment in case they were worried about having to join a long queue between the train and the flight.

Comment: @Crazydre The barriers at Luton Airport Parkway are closed pretty much all the time, with staff present. I've got there around midnight and still found barriers closed + staff there

Comment: OP might have to,join a long queue to get the airport anyway. Luton Aiport Parkway station is 10 minutes away by bus from the airport terminal with buses running every 10 minutes. This can add up to 20 minutes onto a journey which can be a nasty surprise if unexpected. They are planning to build a tramway that will significantly reduce that time by 2020 if things go to schedule.